# Notice: Undefined index: magento_eav_attribute_set in/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php on line 152

Tags: magento2, exception, magento2.3.1, eav-attributes

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade


Notice: Undefined index: magento_eav_attribute_set in /vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php on line 152
```

If I understand correctly this is about missing a table in database, but how to check if we have some application that can use it, because honestly I don't know how to look for it or how this table should look like.

Oh yes, we did `setup:di:compile` and reindex, nothing helps

Update: we create a table with this name and got a new error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1823 Failed to add the foreign key constraint 'EAV_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ENTITY_TYPE_ID_EAV_ENTITY_TYPE_ENTITY_TYPE_ID' to system tables, query was: ALTER TABLE `eav_attribute_set` ADD CONSTRAINT `EAV_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ENTITY_TYPE_ID_EAV_ENTITY_TYPE_ENTITY_TYPE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_type_id`) REFERENCES `eav_entity_type` (`entity_type_id`)  ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: Hello, a similar thing happened to me, i was using a wrong syntax on UpgradeSchema, have you made some recent changes on upgrade and install schema (Some custom module's maybe)?